# Is there a tool that will combine a 32 bit + 64 bit application and pack them together in one 32+64 bit application

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, executable, 32bit-64bit, native-code

In Windows 2008 R2 server (server core installation) [wow64 is no longer a required component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371790%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

I can compile a 32 bit application using the same source code as a 64 bit application (with a few ifdefs here and there).

Is there a tool that puts both versions of my app in one executable so that my 32+64 bit application will run on a pure 32-bit Windows **and** a 64-bit only Windows?

*Note that I am not talking about a packer because the packer itself will be either 32 or 64 bit.*

Comment: You could write a bootstrapper in a .NET language.  It supports AnyCPU as a platform target.  Use IntPtr.Size to know what bitness you got.

Comment: @hans surely AnyCPU relies on WOW64

Comment: @David - no, only if the platform target is forced to x86.

Comment: Winzip/self extract/32bit install launcher app lanuches 32bit or 64bit installer based on OS version

Comment: @sheng sorry thats exactly what i'm looking to avoid

Comment: Does your code have to run on versions of Windows prior to Windows 2008 R2 / Windows 7?

Comment: @Hans And the system loader happens to know about this ruse and does the rest. Sounds like it's the answer.

Comment: Windows does not support fat applications, so there is no way to do this without some sort of bootstrapper.  Do you need the bootstrapper to be a single file or can it be a directory with a run-me file in it?

Comment: @Hans, .NET won't necessarily be available either.  In 2008 R2 this is OK because at least part of .NET will always be present, but it won't work on 2008.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Yes the app should run on at least Windows XP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. An EXE's header is marked with the processor architecture supported by the code contained in the EXE. Use DUMPBIN.EXE -HEADERS  to explore.

EXE's report the "machine" type as:
x86: 0x14C
x64: 0x8664
ARM: 0x1C4

If you want to deploy your app, build a version for x86, a version for x64 (ARM comes later with Win8) and author a setup package (MSI) that can dynamically examine the architecture of the machine onto which you're installing the app, and lay down one or both of the apps. This is how, for example, Adobe are now distributing Flash x86 and Flash x64 in the latest Flash player download.

If you want to build a truly universal binary, build it in .NET and mark it as targetting "Any" CPU. Your app will then be JITted to the architecture of your machine (or the hosting process in the case of an add-in component).

Comment: Of course, this WAS possible last time around... the PE format includes a field for an 16-bit DOS-mode entrypoint... which by default was stuffed with a stub which printed "This application cannot be run in DOS mode." but could be replaced with the 16-bit version of the app.  Too bad they didn't do that again.

Comment: Unfortunately .NET isn't universally available either, at least not prior to Windows 7/2008R2.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Actually, it was only possible *two* rounds ago (DOS+Win16 binary). You can't package a Win16+Win32 binary or a Win32+Win64 binary.

Comment: In principle, I think it should be possible to write a Windows Installer package (MSI file) that unpacks and runs the appropriate version of your application rather than installing it.  I think that's as close as you're going to get to a universal binary that will work on all XP+ systems.  You would need to work within the Windows Installer 2.0 specification, though, because that might be all you've got.